# Where to get the latest GCC version for Windows

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw

I have downloaded the latest version of MinGW that I could find. But the GCC that it installed is only the
latest version 9.2.0 instead of version 10.2. I am quite new to programming and would like to have someone elses insite on this. I have looked around the internet, and haven't found anything that could help me. I would like to update my GCC to 10.2, and would be greatful if someone could explane to me how I can do that. I am very interested in programming, and very motivated to learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using MinGW-w64 over MinGW as it is more up to date and supports both 32 and 64 bit Windows.

If you use [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) shell you can install MinGW-w64 using `pacman`.

There is also a standalone build of MinGW-w64 GCC available from http://winlibs.com/ that requires no installation. Just extract the download and use it.

If you're a beginner you should use an IDE, like [Code::Blocks](https://www.codeblocks.org/) or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

Comment: Yes that's the rout I ended up taking. Thank you for your answer but I have already solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/) says

> To obtain GCC please use our [mirror sites](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html) or our [version control system](https://gcc.gnu.org/git.html)

Alternatively you can get it from [here](http://winlibs.com/)

Comment: The GCC mirror sites or git only provide sources for GCC. There's not much a beginning programmer on Windows can do with that.